# How to use a method from a parent class which returns database values in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

when i run my code i get error message **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function run() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs.............**
i have three class in regards to my problem

1. Init
2. Utilities
3. Withdraw
   init class holds the database connection

```
class Init{
    private $pdo;
    function __construct(){
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $dbName = "**************";
        $password = "";
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$dbName;
            $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->pdo;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function run($sql, $args = NULL)
    {
        $stmt=null;
        
            if (!$args)
        {
            return $this->pdo->query($sql);
        }
        try {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute($args);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            //SEND THIS TO AUDIT SERVICE FOR LOGGING
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

cross section of utilities class

```
require 'init.php';
class Utilities {
    private $db;
    private $msg = [];

    function __construct ($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getUser ($user) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tb WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = $this->db->run($sql, [$user]);
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

cross section of withdraw class

```
include_once "utilities.php";

class Withdraw extends Utilities {
    private $db;

    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }   

    public function withdrawer ($username, $addr, $coin, $amount) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wallet_tb WHERE  username = ?";
        $stmt = $this->db->run($sql, [$username]);
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        $balance = $result["balance"];
        $transact_id = $result["transact_id"];
        $get = $this->getUser($username); //getUser() is from utilities class;
        return $get["email"];
}
```

object

```
    $db = new Init();
    $obj = new Withdraw($db);

    $msg = $obj->withdrawer($user, $addr, $coin, $amount);
    
    echo ($msg);
```

PS: the code (getUser() ) works fine if i am not fetching anything from the database

Comment: Here’s the [essence of your code](https://3v4l.org/44San) as posted with the database stuff removed, no errors. I can induce your error by [removing](https://3v4l.org/ucmd7) the duplicate `$db` from the child class, and I can fix it again by [adding a getter](https://3v4l.org/lBGTE) to the parent class. If this isn’t helpful, you need to inspect `$this->db` for `null` before calling `run()` on it.

Comment: The error implies that you get a null in your variable of the class which calls the `run()` function

Comment: And for the goodness sake get rid of that try catch in your code. it makes not a slightest sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first probkem is that because the $db property is declared "private" in the Utilities class, it can't be directly read or written to by the Withdraw class. You can declare a separate private property with the same name in the child class and the two will be unrelated.

If you want the *same* property visible in both classes, you can declare it "protected" in Utilities, and then don't need to declare it again in Withdraw.

Your second problem (as you discovered) is that PHP doesn't automatically call the parent constructor if you write a constructor in the child class. If the parent class's constructor does everything you need, you can simply not define one on the child class. If you *do* need one on the child class, be sure to call `parent::__construct()` with appropriate arguments, usually at the very beginning or very end of the child constructor.

Finally, it's worth considering whether inheritance is the right tool for this particular job. Inheritance implies an "is-a" relationship between the two classes, in this case "Withdraw is-a Utilities", which doesn't make much sense. If you just want to make functionality from one class available in another, it's usually more flexible and easier to understand to have an instance of one class passed to another, and simply call the public methods (known as "dependency injection"). For example:

```
class Withdraw {
    private Utilities $utilities;
    private DatabaseConnection $db;

    function __construct(Utilities $utilities, DatabaseConnection $db) {
        $this->utilities = $utilities;
        $this->db = $db;
    }   

    public function withdrawer ($username, $addr, $coin, $amount) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wallet_tb WHERE  username = ?";
        $stmt = $this->db->run($sql, [$username]);
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        $balance = $result["balance"];
        $transact_id = $result["transact_id"];
        $get = $this->utilities->getUser($username); //getUser() is from utilities class;
        return $get["email"];
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about dependency injection. I just checked it out and it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out:
parent:: did the magic.

```
function __construct($db) {
   $this->db = $db; // methods in the current class uses the property;
   parent::__construct($db); // this runs the contruct of the other class;
}
```

i don't know if this is the best approach but it sure does work.

Comment: Of course it's not the best, to say the least. First, the problem you stated in your question, is non-existent, as you've been shown in the comments. And also, class  Withdraw should never extend Utilities in the first place. Obviously they have nothing in common. It should accept the utilities class instance as a parameter at best.